# What is difference between "$|++" and "$|=1"

Tags: perl

Can someone please help to clarify? Also, please mention if there are other representation of "$|".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no practical difference that I know of; `$|` only stores a boolean (0 or 1), so incrementing it will never result in any value other than 1.  The micro-micro-optimizers might tell you that ++ is faster.

Decrementing it, on the other hand, acts as a toggle, but I can't think of any good reason to do that in production code: either you want it on or off.

Comment: Micro-micro-micro-optimisers will tell you that *pre*-decrement is faster, which is why Perl transforms `EXPR++` to `++EXPR` in void context. :)

Answer (score 3):

`$|` is super magical, so that `$|++` does the same as `$| = 1;` But why rely on magic when you can just do what you mean (`$| = 1;`)?

Answer (score 2):

the value of $| starts as 0 so $|++ increments from 0 to 1 while $| = 1 sets it to 1. note however that its value can never be set to higher than 1 via incrementation or assignment e.g. $| = 2 still evaluates to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to be fiddling with lowlevel details like `$|` in modern code. This is far better and much more obviously-readable written as

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```